# Increase speed when score gets high or when the fish eats pellets

Tags: java

I want fish to increase speed when score gets high, or when the fish eats some balls

```
public class FlyingFishView extends View
{
    private Bitmap fish[] = new Bitmap[2];
    private int fishX = 10;
    private int fishY;
    private int fishSpeed;

    private int canvasWidth,canvasHeight;

    private int yellowX,yellowY,yellowSpeed = 10;
    private Paint yellowPaint = new Paint();

    private int  greenX,greenY,greenSpeed = 20;
    private Paint greenPaint = new Paint();

    private int  redX,redY,redSpeed = 25;
    private Paint redPaint = new Paint();

    private int score, lifeCounterOfFish;

    private boolean touch = false;

    private Bitmap backgroundImage;
    private Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap life[] = new Bitmap[2];

    public FlyingFishView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        fish[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fish1);
        fish[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fish2);

        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);

        yellowPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        yellowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);

        greenPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        greenPaint.setAntiAlias(false);

        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(false);

        scorePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        scorePaint.setTextSize(70);
        scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        scorePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        life[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hearts);
        life[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.heart_grey);

        fishX = 550;
        score = 0;
        lifeCounterOfFish = 3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight=canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage,0,0,null);
        int minFishY = fish[0].getHeight();
        int maxFishY = canvasHeight - fish[0].getHeight() * 3;
        fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;
        if (fishY<minFishY)
        {
            fishY = minFishY;
        }
        if (fishY>maxFishY)
        {
            fishY = maxFishY;
        }
        fishSpeed = fishSpeed + 2 ;


        if(touch)
        {
             canvas.drawBitmap(fish[1],fishX,fishY,null);
             touch= false;
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(fish[0],fishX,fishY,null);
        }


        yellowX = yellowX - yellowSpeed;
        if(hitBallChecker(yellowX,yellowY))
        {
            score = score + 10;
            yellowX = -100;
        }
        if (yellowX < 0 )
        {
            yellowX = canvasWidth + 21;
            yellowY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()* (maxFishY - minFishY)) + minFishY;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(yellowX,yellowY,25,yellowPaint);

        //Green
        greenX = greenX - greenSpeed;
        if(hitBallChecker(greenX,greenY))
        {
            score = score + 20;
            greenX = -100;
        }
        if (greenX < 0 )
        {
            greenX = canvasWidth + 21;
            greenY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()* (maxFishY - minFishY)) + minFishY;
        }

        //DangerRedBall
        redX = redX - redSpeed;
        if(hitBallChecker(redX,redY))
        {
            redX = -100;
            lifeCounterOfFish--;

            if (lifeCounterOfFish == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Game Over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(getContext(),GameOverActivity.class);
                gameOverIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                gameOverIntent.putExtra("score",score);
                getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
            }
        }
        if (redX < 0 )
        {
            redX = canvasWidth + 21;
            redY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()* (maxFishY - minFishY)) + minFishY;
        }


        canvas.drawCircle(redX,redY,30,redPaint);

        canvas.drawText("Score : " + score ,20,60,scorePaint);

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            int x =(int)  (580 + life[0].getWidth() * 1.5 * i);
            int y = 30;

            if (i < lifeCounterOfFish)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],x,y ,null);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(life[1],x,y,null);
            }
        }





        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],580,10,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],640,10,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],780,10,null);
    }



    public boolean hitBallChecker(int x,int y)
    {
        if (fishX < x && x <(fishX + fish[0].getWidth()) && fishY < y && y <(fishY + fish[0].getHeight()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            touch = true;
            fishSpeed = -22;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that we generally expect users to show some effort when asking questions. Also, we expect them to show us only the relevant code necessary for the question. We also expect them to be precise with what they need. Although your question was really badly formatted at first, the downvotes you got probably come from your lack of research and code dumping.

I'll assume that you're new to asking questions online. This is a difficult skill to master.

I'll assume that you're new to gamedev and to programming in general, that you have found a complete tutorial on the internet and try to change it a bit to understand how stuff works.

I'll also assume that when you mention "speed", you mean the speed of the fish.

---

In the code you have posted, when we search "speed", we find a variable named `fishSpeed`. This variable is used to move the fish right (`fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;`).  It is also incremented each frame (in the `onDraw` function; `fishSpeed = fishSpeed + 2 ;`).

We also see the variable `score`, which is incremented when the fish eats a yellow or green pellet. (`score = score + 10;` and `score = score + 20;`).

We need to combine these two values. We'll use math to make it based on the score:

```
fishSpeed = 2 + (score / 10);
```

This is a first step. Try and see how it goes. Then you can play with maths more, you could also add a variable which counts how many frames your in and further increase the speed of the fish if needed (e.g. `fishSpeed = (2 * frameCounter) + (score / 10);`).

---

Gamedev and math require you to read a lot of code, and really understand what goes on before modifying anything. Making games is hard, there is no instant satisfaction, but once you have something that works, it's really nice!